# Change Discord bot's nickname with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I am making a Discord bot and I want to have it so when `on_ready` it sets the bot's nickname to

`⇨ ⇨ m O d E r A t O r  B o T ⇦ ⇦`

I am also using repl.it:
https://repl.it/@CodingAndMemes/Moderator-Bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [`Bot.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_guild) to retrieve the specific Guild object for the server where you want to set your bot's nickname. Then, you can use [the `me` attribute of the Guild object (`Guild.me`)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.me) to get the Member object that represents your bot in the server. With that Member object, you can use [its `edit` coroutine method (`Member.edit`)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit) and the `nick` parameter of that method, to have it change its own nickname.

For example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = bot.get_guild(123456789)
    me = guild.me
    await me.edit(nick="⇨ ⇨ m O d E r A t O r  B o T ⇦ ⇦")
```

Make sure your bot has permission to change its own nickname. Otherwise, this will raise a [`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Forbidden) error. If you don't know whether your bot will have either the [`change_nickname`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.change_nickname) or [`manage_nicknames` permission](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.manage_nicknames), you should check for it first, e.g. with [`Member.guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions).

See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model if you don't want to get the Guild object by ID.

I would advise you to check that your bot's nickname isn't already what you want it to be first before attempting to change it, i.e. with [`Member.nick`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.nick). That way you're not performing an unnecessary API request. This is especially true if this is going to be in [`on_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready), as it would do so every time you launched the bot and potentially multiple times afterwards.

I'd also advise you not to host a bot on repl.it. It can be used for testing if that's what you're doing, but it's not designed for hosting purposes and there are a lot of disadvantages to attempting to do so.

Comment: You should [accept the answer, rather than comment to say "thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).